# WebSockets on specific route in Nest.js

Tags: websocket, controller, nestjs

I'd like to create specific API route which will be used only WebSocket (`/api/events`) but in all examples of implementing WebSockets on Nest.js I stumbled upon module is imported in `AppModule` and client is emitting events toward the root URL, which I can't do because I have this middleware;

**frontend.middleware.ts**

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { AppModule } from '../../app.module';

export function FrontendMiddleware(
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: Function,
) {
  const { baseUrl } = req;
  if (baseUrl.indexOf('/api') === 0) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: AppModule.getStaticAssetsRootPath() });
  }
}
```

Here is the `EventGateway` and `EventModule`:

**event.gateway.ts**

```
import {
  SubscribeMessage,
  WebSocketGateway,
  WebSocketServer,
  WsResponse,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Client, Server } from 'socket.io';

@WebSocketGateway({ namespace: 'events' })
export class EventGateway {
  @WebSocketServer()
  server: Server;

  @SubscribeMessage('events')
  findAll(client: Client, data: any): Observable<WsResponse<number>> {
    return from([1, 2, 3]).pipe(map(item => ({ event: 'events', data: item })));
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('identity')
  async identity(client: Client, data: number): Promise<number> {
    return data;
  }
}
```

**event.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { EventGateway } from './event.gateway';

@Module({
  components: [EventGateway],
})
export class EventModule {}
```

Is there a way to create controller which will allow server-client communication via `/api/events`?

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it is possible to create the WebsocketGateway on another path. You can just use the options of the WebsocketGateway to configure the underlying IO-Connection:

E.g:

```js
import {
  SubscribeMessage,
  WebSocketGateway,
  WebSocketServer,
  WsResponse,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Client, Server } from 'socket.io';

@WebSocketGateway({ path: '/api/events', namespace: 'events' })
export class EventGateway {
  @WebSocketServer()
  server: Server;

  @SubscribeMessage('events')
  findAll(client: Client, data: any): Observable<WsResponse<number>> {
    return from([1, 2, 3]).pipe(map(item => ({ event: 'events', data: item })));
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('identity')
  async identity(client: Client, data: number): Promise<number> {
    return data;
  }
}
```

This will start the IO-Connection on http://localhost/api/events

Remember to change the connection-path also in your client. It won't be the default /socket.io path anymore, it will be /api/events in your sample.

Answer (score -3):

Websocket is running on the server, not an endpoint. Therefore you cannot have it listen to requests under a specific route, rather just a port, which for Nest's default configuration happens to be the same as the HTTP one.

You could use a reverse proxy like Nginx to redirect the requests towards `/api/events` facing the Websocket server and also handle the redirection to `index.html` without changing even the Websocket server's port. Then you would not need the `FrontendMiddleware` class at all. It is also better since the application does not take the burden of managing request redirections.

Comment: Afaik websockets are just GET requests that never close under the hood. It definitely is possible to have them on a specific route.